# SqlCommand scopes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to insert data into two tables

query:

```
insert into test.products values (123,123,123,123)
insert into test.prices values (456,567,456,SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

I am using this methods:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I wonder if I use this piece of code multiple times at once does the SCOPE_IDENTITY() return identity from single one command or last identity from another running sqlcommands.
I wonder if each started sqlCommand is new SCOPE?

Comment: [SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) *"Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope."* If you are running multiple statements, in different batches, these are all completely different scopes

Comment: Your 2 statements are part of the same batch and therefore in the same scope. The value returned will be the last identity value generated on the current session (connection) per the documentation. Each SqlCommand will execute on a different session due to the `using` block.